# Looking for a good way to write integers to a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

What is a good client-side code construct to store 5 integers that can be added to or removed easily?

I have a number of checkboxes with unique IDs. When clicked, the ID is stored in a cookie so they're available next time the user visits the site.

Is it better for me to have a JavaScript object store the values and write that to a cookie, or write the data directly to the cookie?

Are there any good code samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is limited to integers, you can easily store them in one cookie using a delimiter.

E.g.

```
var theData = [46, 45, 87, 2015, 6];
document.cookie = "mydata=" + theData.join('|');
```

will store a cookie named `mydata` as `46|45|87|2015|6`. Of course you can simply `push` data to the array, etc.